# Implementing laravel lighthouse pagination on the front-end

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, laravel-lighthouse

I'm trying to implement pagination on my site using a nuxt frontend and a laravel backend serving a graphql endpoint using [lighthouse](https://lighthouse-php.com/).

reading the docs about the [pagination](https://lighthouse-php.com/5/eloquent/getting-started.html#pagination) directive has me asking lots of questions about how this works.

Unlike the normal laravel pagination way which is calling `paginate()` on a model which than returns an object with the following items

```
{
   "total": 50,
   "per_page": 15,
   "current_page": 1,
   "last_page": 4,
   "first_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=1",
   "last_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=4",
   "next_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=2",
   "prev_page_url": null,
   "path": "http://laravel.app",
   "from": 1,
   "to": 15,
   "data":[
        {
            // Record...
        },
        {
            // Record...
        }
   ]
}
```

graphql (or at least lighthouse) does it a bit different, mostly the following needs to be done.

you define a query

```
type Query {
    blogs: [Blog!]! @paginate  @orderBy(column: "created_at", direction: DESC)
}
```

Querying it via the graphql-playground with the following params `first : 5, page:1` gives me the following object

```
{
  "data": {
    "blogs": {
      "paginatorInfo": {
        "count": 5,
        "currentPage": 1,
        "firstItem": 1,
        "hasMorePages": true,
        "lastItem": 5,
        "lastPage": 2,
        "perPage": 5,
        "total": 10
      },
      "data": [
        // items
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

Seems simple enough but I'm not entirely sure how to make this work on the front-end

I made a pagination component

```
<template>
  <div class='btn-group bg-white py-2 items-center justify-center'>
    <button class='btn'>Previous</button>
    <button class='btn'>1</button>
    <button class='btn btn-active'>2</button>
    <button class='btn'>3</button>
    <button class='btn'>4</button>
    <button class='btn'>Next</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Pagination'
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

And that's really as far as I have gotten, I've been banging my head for a few hours now reading up on apollo and pagination, but the only examples I have seen so far have been of the infinite scroll variety instead of good 'oll offset based pagination.

Answer (score 1):

On your client side, you will have a Graphql Query, with some Variables. For example:

```
query Blogs($page: Int!, $first: Int!) {
    blogs(page: $page, first: $first) {
      id
      # ...
    }
}
```

So, with Apollo, you have to call it passing those variables, like:

```
data() {
  return {
    page: 1,
  }
},
apollo: {
  blogs: {
    query: gql`...`,
    variables() {
      return {
          first: 15, // it could be dynamic
          page: this.page, // in your component, you will have to change this variable to fetch another page
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, everytime you change the `page` variable, Apollo will make another query to fetch other pages. Usually I use premade components for pagination, like [v-pagination](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/paginations/).

Comment: Hey, I have the query ready, but I'm using tailwind css which means I have to build my own pagination component. Maybe I'll just swap to vuetify